# Mocking Test Failed: Wanted but not invoked

Tags: junit5, project-reactor, spring-test

I'm trying to test `updateUser()` method from `UserServiceImplementation` class. For that, I'm using project-reactor test and JUnit5. When I test `userUpdate()`, I'm receiving ***Wanted but not invoked*** error.  When I google it, I found out `userRepository.save( )` is being called twice. I want to know why?

**UserServiceImplementation Class**

```
@Override
public Mono<User> updateUser(Long userId, UserDto userDto) {
    return userRepository.findById(userId)
            .flatMap(user -> {
                 User updateUser = UserMapper.USER_MAPPER_INSTANCE.toUser(userDto);
                 updateUser.setUserId(userId);
                 return userRepository.save(updateUser);
            })
            .map(Function.identity())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("User not found!")));

}
```

**UserServiceImplementationTest Class**

```
@Test
void updateUser() {
    // given
    Long userId = 1L;
    String username = "user123";
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto(
            username,
            "user user",
            "user123@gmail.com",
            LocalDate.now().toString(),
            9843807187L,
            "password",
            Role.ADMIN
    );
    User user1 = new User(
            1L,
            username,
            "password",
            "user user",
            "user123@gmail.com",
            9843807187L,
            LocalDate.now(),
            Role.ADMIN
    );
    User userUpdate = new User(
            1L,
            username,
            "password",
            "user",
            "user123@gmail.com",
            9843807187L,
            LocalDate.now(),
            Role.ADMIN
    );


    //when
    when(userRepository.findById(userId)).thenReturn(Mono.just(user1));
    when(userRepository.save(any(User.class)))
            .thenReturn(Mono.just(userUpdate));

    // Then
    Mono<User> updatedUser = serviceUnderTest.updateUser(userId, userDto);

    StepVerifier.create(updatedUser)
            .expectNext(userUpdate)
            .verifyComplete();

    verify(userRepository, times(1)).findById(userId);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(userUpdate);

}
```

**Error**

```
Wanted but not invoked:
userRepository.save(
    User(userId=1, username=user123, password=password, name=user, email=user123@gmail.com, phNumber=9843807187, dateOfBirth=2023-02-06, role=ADMIN)
);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementationTest.updateUser(UserServiceImplementationTest.java:168)

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
userRepository.findById(1L);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementation.updateUser(UserServiceImplementation.java:51)

userRepository.save(
    User(userId=1, username=user123, password=password, name=user user, email=user123@gmail.com, phNumber=9843807187, dateOfBirth=2023-02-06, role=ADMIN)
);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementation.lambda$updateUser$0(UserServiceImplementation.java:55)


Wanted but not invoked:
userRepository.save(
    User(userId=1, username=user123, password=password, name=user, email=user123@gmail.com, phNumber=9843807187, dateOfBirth=2023-02-06, role=ADMIN)
);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementationTest.updateUser(UserServiceImplementationTest.java:168)

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
userRepository.findById(1L);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementation.updateUser(UserServiceImplementation.java:51)

userRepository.save(
    User(userId=1, username=user123, password=password, name=user user, email=user123@gmail.com, phNumber=9843807187, dateOfBirth=2023-02-06, role=ADMIN)
);
-> at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementation.lambda$updateUser$0(UserServiceImplementation.java:55)
at com.alertSystem.service.UserServiceImplementationTest.updateUser(UserServiceImplementationTest.java:168)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

`userRepository.save( )` is not being called twice. It said that there are two interactions with userRepository - find and save. The reason of error is probably that entities you are comparing in the test are not equal. Try to add or double check equals method and object which you are comparing with.